# PowerShell string replace using group and replace with $ as prefix

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, I want to replace `$$xyz` with the value of `$xyz` but keep `$xyz` as is.

My solution that I am failing is to replace `$$xyz` and `$xyz` temporarily with something else but different and then resolve them.

```
$var1 = "variable 1"
$var2 = "variable 2"
$var3 = "variable 3"

$str = '$$var1 $$var2 $var3'

# convert $$whatever to @@whatever
$str = $str -replace '\$\$(\w+)', '@@$1'

# convert $whatever to !whatever
$str = $str -replace '\$(\w+)', '!$1'

# convert @@whatever to $whatever
$str = $str -replace '\@\@(\w+)', '$$1'

# convert !whatever back to $whatever
$str = $str -replace '\!(\w+)', '$$1'

# Output the modified string
Write-Output $str
```

My ultimate goal is to run Invoke-Expression which should string interpolate but on `$$variable` instead of `$variable`

As suggested in the comment but not working:

```
$var1 = "variable 1"
$var2 = "variable 2"
$var3 = "variable 3"

$str = '$$var1 $$var2 $var3'
$expected = 'variable1 variable2 $var3'

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($str -replace '\$(?=\$)')

# what I get:
# variable 1 variable 2 variable 3
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($str -replace '\$(?=\$)')` should do what you're after?

Comment: Are you taking into account expansion for `$${var1}` for example ?

Answer (score 2):

First, apply negative lookbehind to escape all ***not doubled** Dollar Sign*s as follows:

```
$str -replace '((?<!\$)\$\w+)', '`$1'
```

> ```
> $$var1 $$var2 `$var3
> ```

(The PowerShell escape character is the grave-accent (`)).

Then, the following should do the trick:

```
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(
    ($str -replace '((?<!\$)\$\w+)', '`$1' -replace '\$\$', '$'))
```

> ```
> variable 1 variable 2 $var3
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this approach might accomplish what you're after:

```bash
$str = '$$var1 $${var2} $var3'
$newstr = $str -replace '(?<!\$)\$(?=[^$])', '@@' -replace '\$(?=\$)'
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($newstr).Replace('@@', '$')
```

This can also work with expansion of [`${...}`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.4#variable-names-that-include-special-characters) which is a valid syntax too.